# Are there alcohol free spirits and how would they taste like?

Tags: spirits, non-alcoholic

There are alcohol free beer and wine, so are there any alcohol free spirits? I know that dealcoholization would make the beer or wine lose its flavor and for spirits the loss would be even larger since the flavor of spirits is largely based on alcohol.

While it is still interesting to taste: What do they taste like.

Comment: Fearing this question would be too broad, I set up a Community Wiki answer for those interested.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alcohol free spirits:

- [Alcohol Free Whiskey](https://blog.thewhiskyexchange.com/2009/06/your-worst-nightmare-alcohol-free-whisky/)
- [Non- Alcoholic Gin](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/7487/5064)

[image: Black Zero Scotch Whiskey]

[Black Zero Scotch Whiskey](https://blog.thewhiskyexchange.com/2009/06/your-worst-nightmare-alcohol-free-whisky/)

Comment: Made this a Community Wiki answer so that all can simply add on to a single response to this question that would be otherwords too broad.

Answer (score 1):

[Arkay Alcohol Free Vodka](https://arkaybeverages.com/shop/arkay-alcohol-free-vodka-flavored-drink/)

> ArKay is perfect for modern Art Cocktails, the taste gives you the same sensation as any other alcohol based cocktails served today.
>
> ARKAY Is Pasteurized The Shelf Life Is 2 Years
>
> 0% – Alcohol; 0% – Calories; 0% – Sugar; 0% – Carb; Gluten Free; Friendly Veggies

[image] [image]